# How do I pass variables from a variable to a pointer struct object?

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

I am trying to pass the variable "val" that I have set to be random over to the pointer HEAD and in the end I want to print out HEAD->val .

I've tried setting it directly using "HEAD->val = n.val;" as you can see but that results in the cout at the end from printing the 10 random numbers.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <stdlib.h>

#include <time.h> 

using namespace std;

struct Cell {
    int val;

    Cell *next;


};




int main()
{

    int MAX = 10;

    srand (time(NULL));

    Cell *c = NULL;

    Cell *HEAD = NULL;

    Cell n;



    for (int i=0; i<MAX; i++) {
        // Use dynamic memory allocation to create a new Cell then initialize the 
        // cell value (val) to rand().  Set the next pointer to the HEAD and 
        // then update HEAD. 

        Cell n = {};
        n.val = rand();
        n.next = HEAD;
        HEAD->val = n.val;



        cout << n.val << endl;
    }



}
```

I am trying to:

1. pass the `val` variable from `n --> HEAD`
2. print out `HEAD -> val`

I know how to do #2 but trying to do #1 is causing problems within other things as I said above. I believe i'm somehow overwriting n's values by doing so but I am wondering why. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your Code looks more Like a C code than a C++ code.

Comment: Your code does not match your comments. 1) _"Use dynamic memory allocation"_ but there is no dynamic memory allocation. 2) _"then update HEAD"_ but the value of `HEAD` is not updated. Did you check that the code as posted in your question still produces the results you describe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually need to allocate the `head` before you can do thins like give it a `val`. [`new`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) can work for this. It would look something like this:

```
Cell *HEAD = new Cell;
```

and, later, you need to [`delete`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete) it when you're done with it:

```
delete HEAD;
```

Though, this isn't ideal. Better is to make use of [smart pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/book/intro/smart_pointers) if you can use them.